# Demux HLS TS stream Split Audio AAC From Video

Tags: objective-c, ios, http-live-streaming

Trying to split HLS TS Stream audio from video, audio is AAC format.
The gole is to have some sort of AVAsset that I can later manipulate and then Mux back to the video.
After searching for a while i cant find a solid lead, can someone give me a educated direction to take on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ffmpeg/libav library for demuxing the ts. To load the audio back as an AVAsset, it might be necessary to load it from a URL, either by writing temporarily to disk or serving with a local http server within your program.

I think you might run into some trouble in manipulating the audio stream, assuming you want to manipulate the raw audio data. That will require decoding the AAC, modifying it, re-encoding, and re-muxing with the video. That's all possible with ffmpeg/libav, but it's not really that easy.